# Where can I find the Scilab balanc() function to calculate the similarity transform to program it in Maxima

Tags: similarity, scilab, state-space, wxmaxima

I'm trying to program the z-transform in wxMaxima which doesn't have it programmed but not by definition but by using the Scilab approach. Scilab to calculate the z-transform first converts the transfer function to the state space, after that the system must be discretized and after that converted to z transfer function, I need this because of some algebraic calculations that I need to do to analyze stability of a system in function of the sample period.

Right now I'm stranded with the function balanc() which finds a similarity transform such that

```
Ab = X^(-1) . A . X
```

as approximately equal row and column norms.

Most of my code in wxMaxima to reach in the near future has been done by translating the Scilab code into wxMaxima, currently I'm writing the tf2ss() function an inside that function the balanc() function is called, the problem is that I couldn't find the code for that function in Scilab installation directory, I've searched info in books and papers but every example starts with the Ab matrix given as an input to the problem, Scilab instead has the option to have as an input only the A matrix and it calculates the Ab and X matrices, so, I need help to make this function exactly as Scilab has it programmed to been able to compare all the steps that I'm doing.

Finally, wxMaxima has a function to calculate similarity transforms but it don't have the same output as Scilab what it means to me that they uses different criteria to calculate the similarity transform.

Note: I've tried to make the calculations in wxMaxima to have Ab and X matrices as elements with variables but the system of equations remains with too many variables and couldn't be solved.

Thanks in advance for the help in doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scilab balanc() is hard-coded and based on LAPACK's dgebal (see the  [Fortran source at Netlib](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d9a/group__double_g_ecomputational_ga411292dd693c20ff9c27650fb7bddf85.html#ga411292dd693c20ff9c27650fb7bddf85)). In the algorithm the operations are quite simple (computing inf and 2-norms, swaping columns or rows of a matrix), maybe this could easily translated ?

A more readable version of the algorithm can be found on page 3 (Algorithm 2) of the following document: https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5766.

Here is a Scilab implementation of Algorithm 3:

```
function [A,X]=bal(Ain)
    A = Ain;
    n = size(A,1);
    X = ones(n,1);
    β = 2; // multiply or divide by radix preserves precision
    p = 2; // eventually change to 1-norm 
    converged = 0;
    while converged == 0
        converged = 1;
        for i=1:n
            c = norm(A(:,i),p);
            r = norm(A(i,:),p);
            s = c^p+r^p;
            f = 1;
            while c < r/β
                c = c*β;
                r = r/β;
                f = f*β;
            end
            while c >= r*β
                c = c/β;
                r = r*β;
                f = f/β;
            end
            if (c^p+r^p) < 0.95*s
                converged = 0;
                X(i) = f*X(i);
                A(:,i) = f*A(:,i);
                A(i,:) = A(i,:)/f;
            end
        end
    end
    X = diag(X);
endfunction
```

On this example the above implementation gives the same balanced matrix:

```
--> A=rand(5,5,"normal"); A(:,1)=A(:,1)*1024; A(2,:)=A(2,:)/1024
 A  = 

   897.30729  -1.6907865  -1.0217046  -0.9181476  -0.1464695
  -0.5430253  -0.0011318  -0.0000356  -0.001277   -0.00038  
  -774.96457   3.1685332   0.1467254  -0.410953   -0.6165827
   155.22118   0.1680727  -0.2262445  -0.3402948   1.6098294
   1423.0797  -0.3302511   0.5909125  -1.2169245  -0.7546739


--> [Ab,X]=balanc(A)
 Ab  = 

   897.30729  -0.8453932  -32.694547  -14.690362  -9.3740507
  -1.0860507  -0.0011318  -0.0022789  -0.0408643  -0.0486351
  -24.217643   0.0495083   0.1467254  -0.2054765  -1.2331655
   9.7013239   0.0052523  -0.452489   -0.3402948   6.4393174
   22.23562   -0.0025801   0.2954562  -0.3042311  -0.7546739
 X  = 

   0.03125   0.         0.   0.    0.
   0.        0.015625   0.   0.    0.
   0.        0.         1.   0.    0.
   0.        0.         0.   0.5   0.
   0.        0.         0.   0.    2.

--> [Ab,X]=bal(A)
 Ab  = 

   897.30729  -0.8453932  -32.694547  -14.690362  -9.3740507
  -1.0860507  -0.0011318  -0.0022789  -0.0408643  -0.0486351
  -24.217643   0.0495083   0.1467254  -0.2054765  -1.2331655
   9.7013239   0.0052523  -0.452489   -0.3402948   6.4393174
   22.23562   -0.0025801   0.2954562  -0.3042311  -0.7546739
 X  = 

   1.   0.    0.    0.    0. 
   0.   0.5   0.    0.    0. 
   0.   0.    32.   0.    0. 
   0.   0.    0.    16.   0. 
   0.   0.    0.    0.    64.
```

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Mottelet, thank you so much again for your help, the code works well on wxMaxima after translated but I have an additional question, you applied to A the original balanc function and  after what I think is your implementation "bal(A)" gaves the same Ab but X has different values, in your "bal(A)" application to A X is the X given by "balanc(A)" multiplied by 32, what I need to know is why "bal(A)" has that cummulative effect, it multiplies for the max value that f takes in the condition "if (c^p+r^p) < 0.95*s".

Comment: with my system with the code translated to wxMaxima code, it gaves the Scilab result the first time that I applied it but the second time X has values multiplied I think for tha maximum value that  f takes in the condition "if (c^p+r^p) < 0.95*s".

Comment: This cummulative effect is also present in Scilab's balanc() implementation, that's the principle of the algorithm (successive multiplications or divisions by 2). It has no importance since powers of 2 are coded exactly.

Comment: yes but tf2ss function in Scilab also uses the similarity transform X to do some calculations and that gives different results with the method you gave me, I didn't finished the code after the balanc() function but I need to ask for the X matrix too

Comment: That's not a problem since state-space realisation of a given transfer function are not unique (even with minimal state dimension). Why would you want to obtain the same result as Scilab then ?

Comment: Well, thanks @Stephane Mottelet again for all your help, I'll try then with the rest of the code